# Create a Typescript + React common library

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I try to create a common React and Typescript common library, and I run into too many difficulties in configuring the project workspace in order to develop both library and app altogether

```
project
├─ app
│  ├─ package.json
│  ├─ tsconfig.json
│  ├─ webpack.config.js
│  ├─ ... (other config files)
│  ├─ node_modules
│  │  ├─ ...
│  │  ├─ @types
│  │  │  ├─ ...
│  │  │  └─ react
│  │  └─ symlink(lib A)
│  └─ src
│     ├─ *.ts files
│     ├─ *.tsx files
│     └─ index.ts
│
└─ libA
   ├─ package.json
   ├─ tsconfig.json
   ├─ other config files
   ├─ node_modules
   │  ├─ ...
   │  └─ @types
   │     ├─ ...
   │     └─ react
   └─ src
      ├─ *.ts files
      ├─ *.tsx files
      └─ index.ts
```

- If the sources from **libA** are in the **app** everything compiles builds and run as expected.
- Under this configuration **libA** is build(tsc) successfully.
- Under this configuration **app** does not compile with the following:

```
../libA/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:2963:13 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'view' must be of type 'SVGProps<SVGViewElement>', but here has type 'SVGProps<SVGViewElement>'.
```

some Googling suggested that I should delete the react types from the node_modules in **libA**, but that would break the convenience of the development process as **libA** will not compile.

---

More details:

```
I develop on Mac.
npm: 6.4.1
node: 8.15.0
typescript: 3.3.3333
webpack: 4
```

tsconfig libA:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "jsx": "react",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

tsconfig app:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": [
      "es5",
      "es6",
      "es7",
      "dom"
    ],
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

I do **not** want to use the **skipLibCheck**, cause the types are the reason I fell in love with typescript in the first place...

It is safe to assume I am doing something completely wrong.. cause I am at it for almost a week on and off and cannot figure the correct configuration.. any guidance is welcome...

---

After further investigation I found out that the only thing that made a difference is whether or not I used a symlink to **libA** by using npm link to it

Comment: This somehow been resolved and I am unsure why.. once I learn I will comment on it here

Answer (score 0):

Best and easiest way is just to use webpack or parcel

You'll want your config to resemble something like this..

```
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const appIndex = path.join(__dirname, "../src/main.tsx");
const appBuild = path.join(__dirname, "../build");
const { TsConfigPathsPlugin } = require('awesome-typescript-loader');

module.exports = {
    context: fs.realpathSync(process.cwd()),
    mode: "production",
    bail: true,
    devtool: false,
    entry: appIndex,
    output: {
        path: appBuild,
        filename: "dist/Components.bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/",
        libraryTarget: "commonjs"
    },
    externals: {
        react: {
            root: 'React',
            commonjs2: 'react',
            commonjs: 'react',
            amd: 'react'
        },
        'react-dom': {
            root: 'ReactDOM',
            commonjs2: 'react-dom',
            commonjs: 'react-dom',
            amd: 'react-dom'
        },
        "styled-components": {
            root: "styled-components",
            commonjs2: "styled-components",
            commonjs: "styled-components",
            amd: "styled-components"
        }
    },
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new TerserPlugin({
                terserOptions: {
                    parse: {
                        ecma: 8,
                    },
                    compress: {
                        ecma: 5,
                        warnings: false,
                        comparisons: false,
                        inline: 2,
                    },
                    mangle: {
                        safari10: true,
                    },
                    output: {
                        ecma: 5,
                        comments: false,
                        ascii_only: true,
                    },
                },
                parallel: true,
                cache: true,
                sourceMap: false,
            })
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".web.js", ".mjs", ".js", ".json", ".web.jsx", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"],
        alias: {
            "react-native": "react-native-web",
        },
    },
    module: {
        strictExportPresence: true,
        rules: [
            { parser: { requireEnsure: false } },
            {
                test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
                loader: require.resolve("tslint-loader"),
                enforce: "pre",
            },
            {
                oneOf: [
                    {
                        test: /\.(tsx?)$/,
                        loader: require.resolve('awesome-typescript-loader'),
                        options: {
                            configFileName: 'tsconfig.prod.json'
                        }
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new TsConfigPathsPlugin()
    ],
    node: {
        dgram: "empty",
        fs: "empty",
        net: "empty",
        tls: "empty",
        child_process: "empty",
    },
    performance: false,
};
```

Important things to know:
libraryTarget: commonjs has to match "module" commonjs in your tsconfig.
awesome-typescript-loader / webpack-cli's can be latest version's to run this.
you will need a tsconfig.prod.json or change the part of the config.

react / reactdom / styled-components are listed as "external" meaning they will not be bundled with your application instead, webpack will look for those modules within the package you're importing into.

Main.tsx should continue only exports to every component you want in the commonjs bundle it should look something like this....
// main.tsx

```
export { Button } from "./components/Button/Button";
export { Checkbox } from "./components/Checkbox/Checkbox";
export { DataTable } from "./components/DataTable/DataTable
```

A quick way to test this build is remove all the "externals" build and then try require("..path...to..bundle").Button and console.log it.

you'll need a index.js and index.d.ts in order to publish to a private or public npm package

EDIT: you'll use that webpack command with something like..

```
  "build": "webpack --config ./folder/to/config//webpack.component-prod.js",
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the direction I want to take it.. I want **tsc** to be able to compile the project without any problems regardless of webpack

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using lerna with yarn's workspace feature.

Your problem is when you have multiple packages depending on same package, then they might refer to a same type definition that exists two copy in different paths(because of symlink).

see: https://github.com/Microsoft/typescript/issues/6496

more detail, search these keywords: "lerna typescript duplicate identifier symlink"

Interfaces can be merged but classes can't. So if you import module from different package, or using lerna's symlink to install dependencies, and there are two different path to find the same type definition, the typecheck on class will fail.

So you need to make sure that there are only one version/position of a package with type definition. That's exactly what yarn's workspace feature did -- install all the sub packages' dependencies at workspace's top level.

But note that the yarn's workspace feature breaks webpack's externals option due to the webpack's module resolve strategy.

Answer (score 0):

So it has been a very very very long journey.. but we have done it.. and since then we have taken this initial POC and converted it into a full scale framework.

[Thunderstorm](https://github.com/nu-art-js/thunderstorm-webapp)